# Is there any Facebook API where I can get account related with entered phone number?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get Facebook account according on the behalf of entered phone number but I don't know how to do this? Is there any API exists to perform this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get a Faceboook account by phone number - it is not even possible to do it the other way around (getting the phone number of a user after he authorizes your App).